# Is there a way to disable triggers globally in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I have db migrations on `TypeOrm` for `Postgresql`. Some of them updates some tables, some tables have some triggers already. I just want to make sure that trigger system is disabled at the very beginning of the migrations.

I know it's possible to disable triggers on a specific table. What I need if to disable/enable db triggers globally on a `Postgresql` database, not for a specific table.

Would it be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

You can only enable/disable at the table level.

Your only approximation to a "command" that does it would be to write a script/stored proc that queries `pg_trigger` to find tables that have triggers and executes

```
ALTER TABLE <table_name> DISABLE TRIGGER ALL
```

And similar to enable them.

Comment: Please don't recommend that statement, since it will break foreign keys. Recommend `ALTER TABLE ... DISABLE TRIGGER USER`, which is safe. There is also `session_replication_role`, but one shouldn't mess with that.